# Why do I have warning "Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'"

Tags: swift

I have updated my Xcode to 12.5. And now I can see next warning:
"Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'"
[image]

What does cause this warning?
(RouterType has to be available only for classes.)

Comment: The warning tells you that the `@objc` annotation implies the conformance to `AnyObject` so you can/should delete `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AnyObject` requires the member that conforms to the protocol to be a class, but you already marked it `@objc`, and in Objective-C only classes can conform to protocols.

Thus requiring `AnyObject` is redundant and you can remove it.

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning behind this warning is flawed, in my view. The terms are not synonyms.

- AnyObject makes this a class protocol.
- `@objc` exposes the protocol to Objective-C.

That’s two different things. The latter may logically imply the former, in that only a class protocol *can* be exposed to Objective-C; but that doesn’t make it redundant. (The type declaration in `let s : String = "x"` is redundant logically, after all, in just the same way — the compiler doesn’t need it — but there’s no warning.)

Apple has made a wrong decision here. I intend to file a bug.